# PHP Increment Alphabetically Looping

Tags: php

i have code like this.

```
$str = 'A';
for ($i = 1;; $i++) {
    $count = ++$str;
    echo 'James said ' . $str.'<br>';
    echo 'Lia said ' . $str.'<br>';
    echo 'Ben said ' . $str.'<br>';
    if ($str == 'D') {
        echo 'STOP';
        break;
    }
}
die();
```

And give me the result like this, which is not what i wanted.

```
James said B
Lia said B
Ben said B
James said C
Lia said C
Ben said C
James said D
Lia said D
Ben said D
STOP
```

Want i want is :

```
James said B
Lia said C
Ben said D
STOP
```

How can i have a result like that?
Or maybe with some other method? Like using array?

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I'm confused - why are you doing this in a loop in the first place?

Comment: what's the use of `for` loop, if you have three fixed lines

Comment: If all you're doing is outputting those four strings, why not just hardcode that result? Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want ouput the Alpahabet incrementally, and codes above are for the example only. The real result will be a hundred lines or more. So i need for looping instead of hard coding hundred lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to increment it each time you use `$str`:

```
echo 'James said ' . ++$str . '<br>';
echo 'Lia said ' . ++$str . '<br>';
echo 'Ben said ' . ++$str . '<br>';
```

Comment: Nice and fast. +1

Comment: That is the result that i want. Thanks!

Comment: As per the other answer you should check you're doing this the best way. I had assumed it is an abstract example of your problem, but if it is exactly what you want to achieve then have a think about a refactor :-)

Answer (score 1):

So much code for a simple task is boring isn't it? You can also do

```
$terms= range('B','D');
foreach(array('James','Lia','Ben') as $i=>$person){
   echo "$person said {$terms[$i]}\n";
}
echo "STOP";
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/728112)**

Comment: I'd say this is the most dynamic answer, although you might want to change `\n` to `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        <?php

        $name = array("James said","Lia said","Ben said");
        $str = 'A';
        for ($i = 0;; $i++) {
            $count = ++$str;
            echo $name[$i] ." ". $str.'<br>';

            if ($str == 'D') {
                echo 'STOP';
                break;
            }
        }
        die();
        ?>
    /* output

    James said B
    Lia said C
    Ben said D
    STOP

*/
```